# Solving functional equation $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)\cos y$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, functional-equations

How can I solve this functional equation, where $x,y$ are any real numbers and $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb R$ is a function such that :
$$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)\cos y$$

---

I tried substituting $x=0$ to get $f(y)+f(-y)=2f(0)\cos y$ . Taking $x=y$ gives $f(2x)+f(0)=2f(x)\cos x$. I similar get some more relations like that, but its not really helping me in finding anything useful. I also think the function must either be $\sin$ or $\cos$ looking at the product to sum formulae. Can anyone tell me how should I solve this?

Comment: Have you *tried* sin and/or cos? It's a reasonable first thought.

Comment: Think about trig product identities and if it makes sense to let $f(x)=\sin(x)$ or $f(x)=\cos(x)$.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius Yes, I know that they are valid solutions, but are they the only ones?

Comment: Let $y=\pi/2$, and you find $f(x+\pi)=-f(x)$.  So it is periodic with $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$.  I'm guessing that Fourier series would be new to you though.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I don't know about them.

Comment: Unless you know more about the properties of $f$, I think this is the best you can do. For example, if you knew $f(x)=mx+b$ were linear, then you could show that any linear function satisfies this property as long as $\cos(y)=1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you could assume (or prove) that $f$ belongs to $\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R})$, then you could do something like this:

Fix an arbitrary $x$, and apply $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}$ to both sides

\begin{align}
f(x+y) + f(x-y) &= 2f(x)\cos(y)\\
f'(x+y) - f'(x-y) &= -2f(x)\sin(y)\\
f''(x+y) + f''(x-y) &= -2f(x)\cos(y)
\end{align}

adding the first and last equality together yields

$$f''(x+y) + f''(x-y) + f(x+y) + f(x-y) = 0$$

for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now substitute $y = 0$ to get $f''(x) + f(x) = 0$ with general solution $$f(x) = c_1 \sin(x) + c_2 \cos(x).$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @dtdarek How can you assume that function is differentiable?

Comment: @mathophile In general I can't, that's why I have a disclaimer at the top of my answer. That being said, such assumptions frequently happen or are even implicit in many cases. Also, even if there is no such assumptions, sometimes it's good to know tricks that allow you to "guess" the solution and then find another method to prove it without that assumption.

Answer (score 8):

Let $P(x,y)$ be the functional equation
$$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)\cos y\text{,}\tag{0}\label{0}$$ $A=f(0)$ and $B=f\left (\frac{\pi}{2}\right )$.

$$P(0,x)\implies f(x)+f(-x)=2A\cos x\text{.}\tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$P\left (x+\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right )\implies f(x+\pi)+f(x)=0\text{.}\tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$P\left (\frac{\pi}{2},x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right )\implies f(x+\pi)+f(-x)=-2B\sin x\text{.}\tag{3}\label{3}$$

So, by $\frac{\eqref{1}+\eqref{2}-\eqref{3}}{2}$,
$$f(x)=A\cos x+B\sin x\text{.}\tag{4}\label{4}$$

Substituting \eqref{4} in \eqref{0}, the functional equation works, regardless of the values of $A$ and $B$. So we have found all the solutions.