# D'Alembert functional equation without odditivity

Tags: trigonometry, functional-equations, even-and-odd-functions

**Problem**

Find the functional $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)cosy$

**Attempts**

Now as I know, the functional equation can be solved more generally as follow:

**General problem**
Find the function$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
 f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)h(y)
\end{align}

with $h$ being an even function.

**General solution**

Choose r such that $h(x − 2r) ≡ h(x)$. Let $f_p$ be a particular solution of the problem and $f$ a general solution.

Choose constants $A$ and $B$, not both zero, such that $Af_p(r) + Bf(r) = 0$. Define
$F(x) = Af_p(x) + Bf(x)$ so that $F(r) = 0$. Interchanging $x$ and $y$ in the original equation, we see that $f(x+y)-f(x-y)=2f(y)h(x)$

Thus,
\begin{align}
f(x-y)=f(x)h(y)-f(y)h(x)
\end{align}

Now as I see, this is great for odd $f$, but my original problem does not contain that kind of condition, and as I suspect, the solution is $f(x)= acosx+bsinx$ is also not odd.

Is there any way this can be done?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Odditivity? What's that?

Comment: **1.** Is the "$ 6 $" in "$ h ( x - 2 r ) 6 \equiv h ( x ) $" a typo? If so, that means you're assuming $ h $ is periodic, which was not given (we only knew $ h $ is even). **2.** [D'Alembert functional equation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/dalemberts-functional-equation/) is of the form $ f ( x + y ) + f ( x - y ) = 2 f ( x ) f ( y ) $, which is different from what you're trying to solve. I suppose "d'Alembert-like functional equation" is a better title. For d'Alembert functional equation itself, take a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1570977/229831).

Comment: For the original problem before generalization, see [Solving functional equation $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)\cos y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1116427/229831).

Comment: **3.** What you get by "interchanging $ x $ and $ y $ in the original equation" is
$$ f ( x + y ) + f ( x - y ) = 2 f ( y ) h ( x ) \text , $$
not the one you've claimed. You seem to have assumed that $ f $ is odd to get that. That assumption is not valid, as we know that the equation can have solutions which are not odd (when $ h ( x ) = \cos x $, one solutions is $ f ( x ) = \cos x $, which is not odd). **4.** The part about "particular" and "general" solutions seem to be irrelevant, as you've made no use of the function $ F $ you've defined.